# Deployment strategies for Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, deployment

I need to come up with a strategy for deploying multiple versions of JAX-WS Web Services. I am currently looking at:

- 1 .war per service and per version.

This offers the maximum flexibility. Deprecation of an old version is straightforward, as well as introducing new versions.

- 1 .war per service and multiple versions.

This involves having 1 .war for all the versions in a service. Less flexibility but a change in a common resource does not mean deploying multiple .wars.

Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pros and cons of various options are compared in-depth [here](http://www.gridshore.nl/2007/08/20/web-service-versioning-in-the-java-world/)